# Swagger request dynamic object

Tags: swagger

I am using Swagger for my api doc. Some Api use dynamic post object, so I just use:

```
parameters:
 - name: region
   in: body
   schema:
     type: object
```

In swagger UI, I can edit the content using "Edit Json" button, but after I click "Save", nothing append to request, it still send empty request when I click the "Send Request" button. So, what am I wrong?

And I test this on http://editor.swagger.io/,  change a post parameter to "object" type , then still can not edit json data.

Comment: I posted an answer to your question even though I was unable to reproduce your problem in Swagger UI.  In my experience, Swagger UI lets you send dynamic properties even without **additionalProperties**.  The same cannot be said of Swagger Codegen.  You'll find **additionalProperties** gives you much better results when you generate client code.  If you still have a problem with Swagger UI, please  clarify the question.

Comment: **zhonshu**, thank you for clarifying the question.  Your original post didn't mention Swagger Editor.  I thought you were having a problem with Swagger UI which is a completely different interface.  I have never tried sending a request from Swagger Editor.  Have you tried Swagger UI?  It may give you a different perspective on the problem. (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `additionalProperties` to define an object with dynamic properties.  For example:

```
parameters:
 - name: region
   in: body
   schema:
     type: object
     additionalProperties:
       type: object
```

That says the request body is a JSON object with no fixed properties.  Clients can specify properties of any type (string, boolean, object, etc.) at run time.  See OpenAPI specification v2.0 for more on `additionalProperties`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but still can not append my json to request.